# Is this static_cast valid/legit?

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

```
double diff = static_cast<int64_t>(a- b);
```

`a` and `b` are of type `int64_t`.

I saw this code in our project. I think it is suspicious, but I am really not sure.
I am familiar with `static_cast`, and I would not write code like this.

Is this static_cast valid/legit? Is it useful?

Comment: What types are `a` and `b`?

Comment: This code looks weird; there's no point in that cast.

Comment: It does seem odd to cast something to an `int64` only to assign it to a `double`. Maybe not "wrong", but "odd". Does your compiler throw any warnings when you use `-Wall -pedantic`? And now that we know `a` and `b` are already of byte `int64_t`, another cast ought to do nothing... Looks like some "left over" code that should have been cleaned out a long time ago.

Comment: The `static_cast<type>(value)` notation is C++ only.  It is invalid in C.  Retagging.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are already `int64_t`s then the `static_cast` is indeed pointless.

Comment: If your compiler has an `int` larger than 64 bit, integral promotion is applied to `a` and `b`, converting them to `int`s. The `static_cast` then would narrow the result down to the range of `int64_t`, invoking UB (signed integer over-/underflow).

Comment: @DyP: I suppose that's possible, but I've never heard of a system having a native `int` type wider than 64 bits.  It's much more likely that the author of this code intended to write `static_cast<double>` rather than guard against an out-of-range error on such an arcane system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cast is valid but does not do anything. I agree that it is suspicious. You should carefully review what the code is supposed to be doing, and if it's correct then you may want to re-write it so that the intent is clearer and so that it doesn't look as suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

If `a` and `b` are both `int64_t`, there is no point to the cast.  It is casting a result of type `int64_t` to type `int64_t`.  It would be like doing this:

```
int a = 10, b = 5;
double c = (int)(a - b); // the cast is not needed, but also not "harmful"
```